# Update nested objects in DynamoDB using AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

So I am working on an app with AWS amplify. I am using a single table design and I am trying to only update one field of the nested object inside of Table. Like for one of my routes I am trying to update the profile field of the UserV0 inside of the SingleTable model.

**Graph QL Schema**

```
type SingleTable @model {
  pk: String! @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["sk"])
  sk: String!
  user: UserV0
}

type UserV0 {
  name: String
  username: String
  email: String
  profile: String

}
```

These are the queries I have been testing with.

```
query getUserInfo {
  getSingleTable(pk: "TEST", sk: "TEST") {
    user {
      username
      name
      profile
      email
    }
  }
}

mutation createTable {
  createSingleTable(input: {pk: "TEST", sk: "TEST", user: {email: "email@email.com", name: "testname", profile: "testPath", username: "testusername"}}) {
    updatedAt
  }
}

mutation updateTable {
  updateSingleTable(input: {pk: "TEST", sk: "TEST", user: {profile: "TESTING", username: "TESTING123"}}) {
    createdAt
  }
}
```

If I run the update mutation above, then the entire user is reset and when I check it in my DynamoDB field the name and email fields are all lost. How can I make it so that when I run the mutation, I only update the profile field(I put in the username field as a test) and leave the other fields without deleting them.

This is what I get after I run createTable then getUserInfo.

```
{
  "data": {
    "getSingleTable": {
      "user": {
        "username": "testusername",
        "name": "testname",
        "profile": "testPath",
        "email": "email@email.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run the updateTable and then getUserInfo in AppSync queries, it returns this.

```
{
  "data": {
    "getSingleTable": {
      "user": {
        "username": "TESTING123",
        "name": null,
        "profile": "TESTING",
        "email": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the name and email fields are returning null from the DynamoDB database, and I checked and the values are just missing. I am pretty sure it is because it sees the user object as a new input. But how do I get it just recognize that I only want to update certain fields in userV0 and not the entire thing.